# Seaborn Scatterplot is hiding series from legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have the follow **Dataframe** with the series:

**Depth: Float**

**Std: Float**

**isValid: Boolean**

I am plotting these data using a **Scatterplot** function from Seaborn lib where **Std is my X-axis, Depth Y-axis and isValid is the function attribute Hue**.

The plot works fine.

The **legend** is the problem. I need to **show** in my legend **Rejected for False and Approved for True values**.

However, when all values inside isValid is True or all values is False, seaborn hide one of my series and show just one value in the legend.

Is there a way to avoid it and keep the Both series in my legend?
Otherwise I will need to do two plot and wouldn't like to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check whether `np.allclose(df["isValid"])` and don't use `hue` if it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hue_order=...`  to always have both values in the legend.
With `.replace` you can replace the boolean hue values to strings.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15,3))
for ax, title in zip(axs, ['Both', 'only False', 'only True']):
     df = pd.DataFrame({'Depth': np.random.randn(100).cumsum() + 20,
                        'Std': np.random.randn(100).cumsum() * .1 + 2,
                        'Valid': np.random.randint(0, 2, 100).astype(bool)})
     if 'only' in title:
          df['Valid'] = 'True' in title
     df['Valid'] = df['Valid'].replace({True: 'Valid', False: 'Unvalid'})
     sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Depth', y='Std',
                hue='Valid', hue_order=['Unvalid', 'Valid'], palette=['tomato', 'limegreen'], ax=ax)
     ax.set_title(title)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with unused hue values in the legend]

Comment: Thank you for the help
Hue_Order was the thing that I was missing. I set it and work fine!